# Grails resource plugin handle waff and ttf

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.3.5 and resource plugin.

I have switched to a new bootstrap based layout.

It generally works fine but I have some problems loading some resources.

In particular the following:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0 
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 
GET http://localhost:8080/static/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff 
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0 
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
GET http://localhost:8080/static/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf 
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0
```

What is required that I get this resources?

Comment: I can't give you much concrete advice because I don't do much front-end development, but you'll be better off switching to asset-pipeline. No development is happening with resources, it's an abandoned plugin and so are many of its addon plugins. Asset-pipeline (and its many addon plugins) however is exactly the opposite - frequent releases, bugs are being fixed, features are being added, and people are actively using it, so there are more users to help with questions. It's not much work to switch and that's a one-time cost.

Comment: Thanks Burt. As I am developing alone at the moment I don't have the resources making that change. But you are of course right and I will taggle that as soon as I can.